# Can eureka server use log4j-over-slf4j?

Tags: spring-cloud

[In the spring cloud eureka documentation:](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#spring-cloud-eureka-server)

> The Eureka server is tied to log4j and doesn’t work with logback, so the dependency configuration has to be tweaked compared to a normal Spring Boot app. The spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server does this for you, but if you add logback transitively through another dependency you will need to exclude it manually, e.g. in Maven

[From the SLF4J documentation:](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j)

> The log4j-over-slf4j module will not work when the application calls log4j components that are not present in the bridge. For example, when application code directly references log4j appenders, filters or the PropertyConfigurator, then log4j-over-slf4j would be an insufficient replacement for log4j.

Is this what the eureka server is doing and what prevents us from using log4j-over-slf4j?

Comment: We need to update the documentation, eureka is no longer using log4j, but is now using logback.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/commit/9357bdd9db72709968ac5988a32306f506282325

Answer (score 0):

In the normal, a logging framework includes an abstraction layer and an implementation, like `slf4j-api` and `slf4j-simple`. `logback` is also an implementation of slf4j. When we use a logger, we use the interface in abstraction layer to do logging. It will find the implementation lib itself.

`log4j-over-slf4j` means we use interface in `log4j`, but use the slf4j implementation to do actual logging. If you use logbak as actual logging implementation,  it will use log properties of slf4j, which is `logbak.xml`.

'The Eureka server is tied to log4j' means we use log4j interface, but spring boot add `log4j-over-slf4j` and `logback` to use slf4j logging framework.

`log4j-over-slf4j` module will not work when the application calls log4j components that are not present in the bridge' means you should not use the classes in the log4j implementation lib in your code. Otherwise, you can not use log4j-over-slf4j to use slf4j implementation.